# calculate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac {1} {(a+b\cos(t))^2}$ such that $a>b>0$ using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm trying to calculate the following integral using the residue theorem:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac {1} {(a+b\cos(t))^2} dt,\quad a>b>0 $$
I've used the substitution $z = e^{it}$, such that $ \cos(t) = \frac{1}{2}(z+z^{-1})$ and $dt = \frac{dz}{iz}$, and I've reached:
$$-i\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z}{((z-z_1)(z-z_2))^2}dz$$
such that:
$$z_1 = -\frac{a}{b} + \frac{\sqrt{(a-b)(a+b)}}{b}$$
$$z_2 = -\frac{a}{b} - \frac{\sqrt{(a-b)(a+b)}}{b}$$
I've shown that $z_1$ is inside the unit circle, and it's a second-order pole, so by the residue theorem:
$$-i\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z}{((z-z_1)(z-z_2))^2}dz = 2\pi Res(f,z_1)$$
so I've calculated the residue using:
$$Res(f,z_1) = \lim_{z \to z_1} \frac{d}{dz} \left(\frac{z}{(z-z_2)^2} \right) = -\lim_{z \to z_1} \frac{z+z_2}{(z-z_2)^3}$$
and found that:
$$Res(f,z_1) = -\frac{z_1+z_2}{(z_1-z_2)^3} = \frac{ab^2}{4(a-b)^{3/2}(a+b)^{3/2}}$$
And in conclusion, the integral equals:
$$\frac{ab^2\pi}{2(a-b)^{3/2}(a+b)^{3/2}}$$
But when I check with an integral calculator, I get that it's wrong. 
I don't know where is my mistake, I've checked every detail until my eyes hurt. I think I'm missing something crucial here, maybe a technical error.perhaps there's a simpler way of calculating it using the residue theorem? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does it help if you multiply the expression by the missed factor $\frac4{b^2}$?

Comment: What expression? The resulting integral, residue, or $z_{1,2}$ ?

Comment: The integral. Since $a+b\cos t$ has $z^2$ coefficient $b/2$ but your integral's integrand's denominator is monic, you're missing an overall factor of $4/b^2$.

Comment: The resulting integral.

Comment: I might be missing something. I've used:
$$ (a+b \cos(t))^2 = \frac{1}{z^2} \left(\frac{b}{2} z^2 +za + \frac{b}{2} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{z^2} \left((z-z_1)(z-z_2) \right)^2$$.
What have I not looked into?

Comment: The denominator should be $b^2[(z-z_1)(z-z_2)]^2$.

Comment: Ok, I see that the polynomial that I got is not the same. I'll try to fix that. Thanks you very much!

Comment: And instead of $-i$ before the integral you have $-4i$, as pointed out above.

Comment: Alright, now my integral is correct. thank you all for helping me! I knew I missed something.